# Como puedo bloquear un usuario al 3 intento

Tags: javascript, html5

¿Como puedo bloquear un usuario al 3 intento?
Estoy haciendo un login de usuario y contraseña. Me piden que si un usuario hizo 3 intentos fallidos para loguearse se le bloquee la cuenta, según la función en JavaScript tendría que bloquear al usuario después de 3 intentos fallidos, pero el bucle solo se queda en "Te restan 2 intentos" y aunque me vuelva a equivocar solo se queda en "Te restan 2 intentos".[image: Está es la imagen de la función en JavaScript]

Comment: Yo quizás usaría [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (o [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)) para ir guardando el conteo de los intentos y así poder consultar cuantos lleva. Por cierto, no uses imágenes para poner código en la pregunta. No son útiles para reproducir tu problema o ayudarte mejor. Copia el código y pégalo en la pregunta y usa el botón `{}` del editor de este sitio para marcarlo como código, gracias.

Comment: Evita poner imágenes para compartir código, copiar y pegar es mucho más efectivo porque la gente que desea colaborar a la solución, tiene la facilidad para reproducir el escenario. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error es porque tienes una variable que siempre declaras en 3 cuando se llama la función **iniciarsesion**.

Lo que tienes que cambiar es el código a esta manera:

```
var saldoPrincipal = 2500.00;
var conteo = 3;

function iniciarsesion(){
user = .... //Tu código
pass = ... //Tu código

//conteo = 3 -- Tienes que eliminar esto de la función y colocarlo arriba como está en el ejemplo
```

De esa manera irá bajando hasta llegar a 0.

Espero te sirva la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, si me funcionó.